# Unity can't import a blender file

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

My blender model won't import to unity and it just looks like this

[image: Picture of the unity project viewer showing wrong thing]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I move my file out of the project and back in, it fixes it for some reason.